# Labeling linear functions in R, by using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, label

I have the following code:

```
v1 <- function(x){x/0.5-0.5}
v2 <- function(x){x/0.3-0.5}

library("ggplot2")


p <- ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0,1)), aes(x=x)) 

p +
  stat_function(fun=v1, geom="line") + 
  stat_function(fun=v2, geom="line") + 
  xlab("θ") + ylab("v(θ)") +
  theme_classic()
```

When I execute my code I want the generated functions to be labeled as `v1` and `v2` respectively. How can I achieve the desirable result?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit further? Your plot draws 2 lines - did you want the 2 lines labelled as `v1` and `v2` with additional text near them?

Comment: One way is to use a legend, e.g. `p +
  stat_function(aes(lty = 'v1'), fun=v1, geom="line") + 
  stat_function(aes(lty = 'v2'), fun=v2, geom="line") `

Comment: @Ben Sorry for my late reply... I want the two lines to be labelled as `v1` and `v2`, respectively. No additional text

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```r
p +
  stat_function(fun=v1, geom="line") + 
  stat_function(fun=v2, geom="line") + 
  xlab("θ") + ylab("v(θ)") +
  theme_classic()+
  annotate("text",x=0.5,y=v1(0.5)-0.2,label="v1")+
  annotate("text",x=0.5,y=v2(0.5)+0.2,label="v2")
```